# Span's all next to each other

Tags: html, css

What is going on here, I has tried floating the spans to the left, I have tried displaying them inline-block, inline ect... nothing seems to be working, I want any spans in the "filters" div to all go next to each other on a horizontal line!

[image: See, any spans that don't fit are going below...]

HTML:

```
<div class="filters">
                <span style="background-image:url(images/filters/grayscale.jpg)">Grayscale</span>
                <span style="background-image:url(images/filters/smooth.jpg)">Smooth</span>
                <span style="background-image:url(images/filters/contrast.jpg)">Contrast</span> 
                <span style="background-image:url(images/filters/brightness.jpg)">Brightness</span> 
                <span style="background-image:url(images/filters/colorize.jpg)">Colorize</span>          
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
.filters {
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    height:8em;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
    overflow:scroll;
}
.filters span {
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:175px;
    height:65px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-top:2.2em;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: How could they be next to each other when there's no width to fit them all?

Comment: decrease each span's width

Comment: div's are doing the same thing

Comment: @helion3 it should scroll to give them more room.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `width` from `100%` to a larger value (in % or px) and a containing `div` if you want the user to scroll horizontally through the `span`s.

[SEE JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6cmT4/)

```
.container {
    width:300px;
    height:8em;
    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
.filters {
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    height:8em;
    width:1000px;
    border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
}


<div class="container">
  <div class="filters">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have defined a width in px instead of %, no luck. I don't want to make the container big enough to contain all the span's. I want to be able to scroll horizontally.

Comment: How wide did you make the filters div? Does `.filters` have a parent? That parent should be the one with the width set tightly

Comment: The same size as it's container, it needs to stay within the main div. 700px

Answer (score 0):

## Edit: Solution

Here is you fiddle working: [Working jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/DpfBj/3/)

## Original Answer

Use `white-space: nowrap;` css for surrounding container. If you want to get rid of autospaces between the spans as well concatenate them with `<!-- -->` html comments.

HTML:

```
<div class="filters">
        <span>Grayscale</span><!--
     --><span>Smooth</span><!--
     --><span>Contrast</span><!--
     --><span>Brightness</span><!--
     --><span>Colorize</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.filters {
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    height:8em;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
    overflow:scroll;
    white-space: nowrap; /* added */
}
.filters span {
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:175px;
    height:65px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-top:2.2em;
    /*float:left; removed*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change your code in the following way,

```
.filters {
    position:relative;
    background-color:#1a1a1a;
    height:8em;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:0px 0px 15px 15px;
    overflow:scroll;

}
```

then for each span, you have to change **left: 0px** to the amount you want the filter effect to move from the left side.

```
.filters span {
    position:absolute;
    left: 0px;
    margin:10px;
    border-radius:15px;
    background-size:contain;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:175px;
    height:65px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding-top:2.2em;
    float:left;
}
```

I have added **position:relative;** on filter box,

and **position: absolute;** and **left: 0px;**

Comment: Now all of the span's are in the same place and next to each other.

Comment: yes it would be, you have to specify left: AMOUNTpx for every .filters span

Comment: Hmm, not very dynamic then if I want to add more.

Comment: that's true, [http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/] gives you an example about nth-child css formatting. can you js-fiddle your code then i can experiment with you for a solution.

Comment: I also would like to scroll to the left and right using javascript instead of having scroll bars visible.

Comment: If you can use javascript, then you can easily determine the location of the next span and assign left: AMOUNTpx values based upon index of span inside the filters.